# check a checkbox in word using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation

I have a word doc with several checkbox fields. I can fill the text fields, but haven't figured out how to check checkboxes.

I can't just make a macro in word and see how word does it because to use the keyboard to check the box (space bar), you have to enable document protection, which disables macro creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried setting an old fashion **Word2003 Checkbox with VBA**. Worked with that piece of code:

```
' demo purposes - added a command
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' FormFields refers to Word2003 FormFields
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
        ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True
    End If

   ' ContentControls refers to >= Word2007 Controls - thx to StevenDotNet for the hint
   ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Checked = True
End Sub
```

[image: WordCheckBoxControl_Form]

On the other hand I created a **VS2012 WordProject with VB.net** and added some code to check the box on load.

```
Private Sub ThisDocument_Open() Handles Me.Open
    Me.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between `ActiveDocument.FormFields` and  `ActiveDocument.ContentControls`? I tend to avoid VBA because of stuff like this but now I'd like to find out.

Comment: It looks like `ActiveDocument.FormFields` refers to Word2003 FormFields, and `ContentControls` refers to >=Word2007 Controls.

Comment: If Main.chkInitial.Checked = True Then oWord.ActiveDocument.FormFields("Initial").CheckBox.Value = True

Comment: Is this another question/bug? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox has a `Value` property. You can set this property to `True` or `False` to check or uncheck the checkbox.

**EDIT**

I wrote a little macro that ticks all boxes in the active document. You can edit it to suit your needs. VBA is really nasty though, it took me around 15 minutes to figure this out.

```
Sub CheckAllBoxes()
    Dim ctrl As ContentControl
    For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If ctrl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
            ctrl.Checked = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might be referring to a regular vb.net checkbox. I'm asking about a checkbox form field from within a word document. If that's what you're talking about too, what do I need to select in my range (or whatever) and what do I execute?

Comment: My mistake, but it's not that much different for Word content controls. The checkboxes have a `Checked` property that's either true or false. You set it in the same way you'd change the text in a textbox.

Comment: Are you using vb.net or vba?